# When do we get the ConnectionFailureError with DirectLine Speech bot?

Tags: azure-cognitive-services, speech, direct-line-botframework

I am using C# SDK for Direct Line Speech to try and create a back and forth seamless communication from the bot and my voice app, but the websocket stream keeps getting disconnected after first or second back-and-forth. I see this error in Connector_Cancelled event:

`Connector_Canceled:Error ConnectionFailure : Connection was closed by the remote host. Error code: 1011. Error details: Internal server error. SessionId: 08e399e7615b499eb1b38ba2ffc6b283`

How do I troubleshoot this issue and how do I correlate the SessionId. I don't see this session id is different each time even between the different events like Connection_SessionStarted and Connection_SessionStopped.

Answer (score 0):

When the speech recognition service encounters an unrecoverable error it breaks the connection. On the client this is seen as connection failure. Typically **Internal Service Error** indicates this was not an error caused by the client. Errors cause by client error typically include actionable details.

To raise a support ticket follow the guidelines in the [Help and support options](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/speech-service/support) for cognitive services.

To troubleshoot the issue further [detailed client logs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/Speech-Service/how-to-use-logging) would be helpful.